# Conditioning in probability Tree diagrams

Tags: probability

[image]

Could someone help me find the probabilites of the ones I have written above? I have attempted several times but each time I get different probabilites. I am very confused with conditional probability. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}$Read $\P(\ldots)$ as the probability for passing through a route containing the listed nodes.

$\P(n_{11})$ is evaluated by tracing all four of the routes to node $n_{11}$ and adding the joint probability for each of these.

$$\P(n_{11})~=~{\P(n_0,n_1,n_5,n_{11})+ \P(n_0,n_2,n_5,n_{11})+\P(n_0,n_2,n_6,n_{11})+\P(n_0,n_2,n_7,n_{11})}$$

$\P(n_2,n_{11})$ is similarly evaluated by tracing all three of the routes which pass through node $n_2$ to reach node $n_{11}$, and adding the joint probabilities for each of those.

> $$\P(n_2,n_{11}) ~=~ {\P(n_0,n_2,n_5,n_{11})+\P(n_0,n_2,n_6,n_{11})+\P(n_0,n_2,n_7,n_{11})}$$

The conditional probabilities are then evaluated by using the definition, as usual.$$\P(n_2\mid n_{11})=\dfrac{\P(n_2,n_{11})}{\P(n_{11})}\\\P(n_2\mid n_{2})=\dfrac{\P(n_2,n_{11})}{\P(n_{2})}$$

Comment: P(n2) would just be 1/3 since there's 1/3 of the time the n2 path will be chosen out of n1, n2, n3. Or is it the case that I need to add up the probabilities that passes through n2 (which there are 5 cases)?

Comment: Yes, you are given that $\P(n_2)=1/3$, so you may use that.  Or you may sum up the probabilities for the *seven* routes that pass through node $n_2$ if you have them.  If the system is consistent then they will be the same.